# Using multiple shells in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, cygwin

In Jenkins you can choose which shell you want to use to execute shell scripts, but it only lets you choose one.

Some of our jobs need to use Cygwin 32-bit shell and other Cygwin 64-bit shell. To get around this we configured Jenkins to target the 32-bit cygwin instance and for 32-bit jobs we can use the Shell Script build step. Unfortunately, for jobs that need to use the 64-bit instance we use a Batch Script in Jenkins and invoke the 64-bit instance of cygwin shell and run a shell script (.sh) that we maintain in source control.

We'd really like to be able to set the shell executable per job instead of per jenkins instance so that we can put some of the more simple shell commands in a shell script build step. Plus this would keep our 64-bit and 32-bit jobs the same.

So, does anyone know of a way to set that shell executable per job?